# Changing UI Style in MahApps.Metro MessageDialog buttons

Tags: mahapps.metro

I have a custom theme for my application and I would like to change the Style of the buttons (color, border, etc..) of the Buttons generated by the MessageDialog to match my application theme. Is there a simple way to do this in XAML ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your application theme in the app.xaml like below the standard mahapps.metro styles usually do a pretty good job of matching the application (including the mahapps MessageDialog).

app.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Red.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

sample button styles

```
   <Button Style="{DynamicResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" />
   <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"/>
```

You can also change styles if sections of your code

```
 <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>
```

You should check out [MahMappsmetro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) and their [Github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

Hope that is what you were asking.